# Python NameError: name 'isAnagram' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.7

I want to print whether a number is an anagram or not from the user input. I get an error saying nameError. [image: Error message]

And this is my code for checking an input for an anagram.

```
n = input("Enter a long number")
factor = 2
factor_anagram = False
while factor < 10:
    if isAnagram(n, factor):
    print(n, "is an anagram with factor", factor)
    factor_anagram = True 
    factor += 1
if not factor_anagram:
     print("No")
```

Do I need to create a class? I tried creating an isAnagram class as well. But my implementation did not solve the issue.

Comment: Where do you define `isAnagram`?

Comment: There is no built-in `isAnagram` function. You have to define one your own.

Comment: You don't need to create a class. You need to create a function :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use isAnagram(n, factor) as a built in function like print("xyz").  isAnagram() is not a built in function, so you will have to define it at the top of your code.  It can look like this:

```
def isAnagram(n, factor):
    if (whatever comparison needs to be made here):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Now when you call the isAnagram function, either True or False will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

isAnagram does not exist in the default Python library - you have to define it yourself. From the way you're attempting to use it, you want to create a function

```
def is_anagram(n, factor):
    # Your code here
    # return True or False
```

You can then do something like `if is_anagram(n, factor):`.